# How to open UWP app using powershell or command line and close uisng powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line, uwp

I am Developing the UWP (for LOB), so I want to do the following

1. I want to open my UWP App using command line or Powershell scripting
   then close that after as i need to register the BG Task for Tile Update
2. Also how to minimize the same app (Not by user action) or close the app after some seconds or minutes

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to automate launching a UWP is to use [URI activation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

You can track a timer into your UWP app and just call `CoreApplication.Exit`. The key thing to remember is that you might get suspended.

Comment: i tried using the setting the protocol uisng the Package manefesto, but after that what should i do to call from powershell, i tried using Process-Start , eg. Process-Start namedaylaunch  which is the sample app . But i got below error when i try to run et-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Start-Process'.

Comment: DO i need o give the full path in the start command like start C:\ProgramFiles\windowsApp\.....

Comment: No. The point of the protocol URI activation is you'd make it something like "mylobapp" and then do ``start mylobapp:``